# Returning the results in the 'SAME ORDER' as the input param

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

In the below query what should I do to get the results in the same order as the input param.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT a.num AS Num, a.photo as Photo , row_number() over (order by (select 0)) rn
            FROM tbl a (nolock) WHERE a.num IN (' + @NumList + ') '
```

I pass in to the @NumList param the following (as an example):

```
1-235,1-892,2-847,1-479,3-890,1-239,2-892
```

This works fine, however I need the results returning in the 'SAME ORDER' as the input param.

I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06498/5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If @NumList contains unique values you could use [CharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323%28SQL.90%29.aspx) to find their position within the param ex:

```
order by charindex(a.num, @NumList)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a local temporary table `#numbers`. Ensure that it has an auto-increment identity column.
2. Insert the numbers from `@NumList` into `#numbers` in the correct order.

   - Split `@NumList` at the commas and turn the individual values into rows. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows) for ideas how to do this.
   - Alternatively, turn `@NumList` from a `VARCHAR`-typed variable into a table variable. (That way, you might even be able to use it directly, i.e. in place of `#numbers`.)
3. Modify your query so that rows from `tbl a` are joined to `#numbers`. Also, add an `ORDER BY` clause that sorts the result by the auto-increment identity column of `#numbers`.